# How to have private endpoints on a public webserver?

Tags: html, node.js, express, nginx, webserver

Let's say I a web server with most of the endpoints publicly accessible. I want **some of them to be accessible just by me** (though it could be a group of people eventually).
I'm looking for the most bare-bone solution. I would not want to implement users accounts for example.

The webserver is implemented with [express](http://expressjs.com/) and nodejs.
I run the server with nginx in case that helps, but if possible implemeting this at app level would be better.

Comment: You're probably looking at middleware that requires an API key in the request, or that limits requests to your IP.

Comment: ceejayoz, I'm not that familiar with middlewares but I'm now checking the docs. Are you saying something like adding a middleware that checks for example a query parameter containing the API key?

Comment: Yes. Apply it to the relevant routes; the middleware can basically just be "if the API token is missing or wrong, reject the request". Should only be a handful of lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds great. Feel free to answer it "officially" so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small snippet you can use, pass in Basic Authorization header with PassKey in all private API requests
[image]

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()


const tempauth = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]!=="PassKey")
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized")
    else
    next()
}
app.get("/", tempauth, (req, res)=>{
res.send("Access granted")
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("Server running on 3000")})
```